# "Windows 7 SP1 Remote Desktop Enabler" after upgrade?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8

There is no remote desktop available into Windows 7 Home Premium (although you can remote desktop into other computers). Actually, it is just disabled. Using the **Windows 7 SP1 Remote Desktop Enabler**, you can enable it (as well as allowing multiple concurrent RDP logins).

If you upgrade to Windows 8, will this still work? Otherwise, is there an equivalent enabler for Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 Pro and Enterprise let you enable an RDP server through [the control panel](http://www.guidingtech.com/13469/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-8/).
A faster way is to open the run box and type **SystemPropertiesRemote.exe** then check the corresponding checkbox to allow connections.

Comment: except in the basic edition, right?

Comment: Oh you are talking about setting up the computer as an RDP server, I've updated the answer to reflect this, and you are right, there is no server in the basic version. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart